# add looping link on an image

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to add links on the cabinet photo

[image]

So each drawer will have a link that will redirect to another page when clicked.
So when I have more than 3 links a new cabinet will appear.

All the folders are directly from my directory from my computer.

```
$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\OJT\IRMS\TestFiles';

$filecounter = (count(scandir($dir))-2);//4
$numberofcabinets = ceil($filecounter/3); //2
echo $numberofcabinets;

if ($handle = opendir('TestFiles')) {                                                              
  for($cabinetcounter=0;$cabinetcounter<$numberofcabinets;$cabinetcounter++){                 //for,//cabinetimg
      echo "<div class='folder'>                                                                      
              <img src='img/Cabinet.jpg' width='200' height='170'>";

      for($drawer=0;$drawer<=3;$drawer++){                                                        //for
          while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {  //start of listing file name

              if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {  //start of '..' exclusion                                                      
                  echo "<div class='drawer$drawer'><a href='search.php?entry=$entry'>$entry</a></div>";             //content
              }
           }
       } //for
       echo "</div>";
   } //for
}

closedir($handle);
```

Comment: and your problem is???

Comment: Why you have `for ($drawer <= 3){ while (!false)`? Doesn't it creates too much drawers?